# What is wrong with this MYSQL statment?

Tags: mysql

For the life of me i've been staring at this for 5 minutes and can't figure out why MYSQL is spitting it back on me

```
UPDATE noti SET read=(read+1) WHERE id='2068';
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your table look like? What else are you not telling us?

Comment: In the future, please post the error message you get as well. This one was easy to spot but not all are. This will help you avoid a downvote :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL, `READ` is a reserved keyword.  You'll need to enclose the column `read` in backquotes to keep it from being misinterpreted as the `READ` keyword and correctly interpreted as your column name.

```
UPDATE noti SET `read`=(`read`+1) WHERE id='2068';
```

More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 2):

`read` is one of [MySQL's reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Try this:

```
UPDATE noti SET `read` = `read` + 1 WHERE id = '2068';
```